# terraform plan giving Error: Unsupported argument in child module of AWS RDS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I am creating a two-tier architecture using Terraform and AWS modules. I have a Root folder and a child folder where I am getting this below error. I have declared a variable in Child folder and Root folder named as`'db_name'` and calling it out in *rds.tf* and *main.tf* files. But running `terraform plan` command is giving the below error:

```
Waiting for the plan to start...

Terraform v1.4.2 

on linux_amd64

Initializing plugins and modules...

│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on child-module/rds.tf line 54, in resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance":
│   54:   db_name                = var.db_name
│ 
│ An argument named "db_name" is not expected here.
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)
```

**child_module Folder**

rds.tf

```
.
.
resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance" {
  allocated_storage      = var.db_allocated_storage
  engine                 = var.db_engine
  engine_version         = var.db_engine_version
  instance_class         = var.db_instance_class
  db_name                = var.db_name
  username               = var.db_username
  password               = var.db_password
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  multi_az               = true
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnet_group.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.db_security_group.id]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}-db-instance"
    Environment = var.env
  }
.
.
```

variables.tf

```
.
.

variable "db_name" {
  description = "The database name"
  type        = string
}
.
.
```

**Root Folder:**

main.tf

```
.
.
module "create_two_tier_aws" {
  source = "./child-module"

  env                       = var.env
  aws_region                = var.aws_region
  vpc_cidr_block            = "172.16.0.0/16"
  public_subnet_cidr_block  = ["172.16.0.0/24", "172.16.1.0/24"]
  private_subnet_cidr_block = ["172.16.10.0/24", "172.16.11.0/24"]

  ec2_name = var.ec2_name
  ssh_key  = var.ssh_key

  db_name     = var.db_name
  db_username = var.db_username
  db_password = var.db_password
}
.
.
```

variables.tf

```
.
.
variable "db_name" {
  description = "The database name"
  type        = string
  default     = "terraformdatabase1"
}
.
.
```

Can someone please provide your insight or suggestion on what am I missing here?
Thank you for reading through this.

I checked and rechecked everywhere the variable `db_name` was defined and called out.

Comment: which DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `db_name` depends on the Database Engine you are creating.

As per the terraform resource [`aws_db_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#db_name) docs.

> Note that this does not apply to Oracle or SQL Server engines. See the [AWS documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance.html#options) for more details on what applies for those engines. If you are providing an Oracle db name, it needs to be in all upper case. Cannot be specified for a replica.

For `Amazon RDS Custom for SQL Server` and `SQL Server`

`--db-name` parameter is Not applicable and Must be null.

Hence you should pass a default `null` value to your variable `db_name` in the child module to make it an optional attribute in the module and then can get rid of the attribute in your root module whenever you are creating either of `Amazon RDS Custom for SQL Server` or `SQL Server` database engines.

```
variable "db_name" {
  description = "The database name"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}
```

```
module "create_two_tier_aws" {
  source = "./child-module"

  env                       = var.env
  aws_region                = var.aws_region
  vpc_cidr_block            = "172.16.0.0/16"
  public_subnet_cidr_block  = ["172.16.0.0/24", "172.16.1.0/24"]
  private_subnet_cidr_block = ["172.16.10.0/24", "172.16.11.0/24"]

  ec2_name = var.ec2_name
  ssh_key  = var.ssh_key

  db_username = var.db_username
  db_password = var.db_password
}
```